# Excel VBA How can I automatically run a function upon manually aborting a script

Tags: vba, excel

I minimize the Excel ribbon at the start of my script.

```
If Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height >= 120 Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

When I pause on a breakpoint and then Stop the macro, this leaves the ribbon hidden.

Is there a way to automatically run another script/sub/function upon pressing the Stop button on the toolbar?

To clarify:

I am not stopping the script via VBA, but by pressing the stop button on the toolbar. At any given time I have up to a dozen breakpoints set in this 1800+ line macro, and when I kill the macro I was hoping there might be a VBA/VBE event that I can tap into to run a clean-up script.

Comment: Why not just unhide? There's logic, I assume, in why you're stopping the macro at a certain part?  Why not use that logic to reset the ribbon?

Comment: No, I am not stopping the script via VBA, but by pressing the `stop` button on the toolbar. At any given time I have up to a dozen breakpoints set in this 1800+ line macro, and when I kill the macro I was hoping there might be a VBA/VBE event that I can tap into to run a clean-up script.